# Does Sql Server Database Mail use threads while sending mail?

Tags: sql-server, database, email, multi-threading

We are using Sql Server 2008 Database Mails to send emails to our website visitors. I don't know whether Sql Server sends mail one by one by picking up from the queue or it will use threads to send emails in simultaneous fashion.

If database mail feature uses threads, is there any way to increase number of threads to run concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Since dbmail uses Service Broker that means from the queue.

BOL:  ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_4deptrbl/html/9e4563dd-4799-4b32-a78a-048ea44a44c1.htm

**** I didn't realize it but this question is a duplicate.  This question was also posted on stackoverflow and was migrated over from  there.  This question should be closed *******